# i installed Ubuntu 11.10 along with win7 and win8.., but it shows me 3 Ubuntu os's in the boot(in startup)

Tags: dual-boot

I've installed Ubuntu 11.10 along with win7 and win8.., but it shows me 3 Ubuntu OS in the boot (in start up). But it shows me all Ubuntu OS's are at the same drive itself, when I selected those remaining to those two are also redirected to the same OS which is installed in the same drive. Will you please tell me how to remove those excess(extra 2 Ubuntu) OS options from BOOT menu ?

Answer (score 2):

If you mean the top 3 as shown in this random image:

[image]

Then this is normal (Besides the Windows one since this will only show when you have Windows installed too).

- recovery mode is for when you can not boot into Ubuntu.
- memtest86+ is to test your memory

If you do not want these shown you can use the program in this answer to have them not shown during boot (they are still there in case you do need them someday):

[How do I hide an entry from grub?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/280026/how-do-i-hide-an-entry-from-grub/280029#280029)

Answer (score 0):

You will find a lot of information on editing grub with the following link.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2

Comment: sorry Joseph Oliver that link doesn't gives me any idea that what i am looking for.