# How do I hide GRUB entries?

Tags: 13.04, grub2, windows, windows-8

I recently followed [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-system-uefi-supported) guide to dual-booting OEM Windows 8 and Ubuntu, and now I've got an awful GRUB menu full of redundant entries. All I want are two entries: one for Ubuntu, and one for Windows. I'd also like to be able to rename them, since the entry for Windows 8 has a name that doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 1):

First try grub-customizer, [see this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/280026/how-do-i-hide-an-entry-from-grub?rq=1), but you should know that grub-customizer has some issues with the newest grub-2.00.

If you like the manual editing way, open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and run

```
gksudo /etc/grub.d/40_custom && gedit /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

Here you will create YOUR custom grub entries. If you have another Linux system (Windows no matters), then you must update these custom entries by hand every time a new kernel arrives in the other Linux system (not Ubuntu).

Now you must have two documents opened, the one (`40_custom`) is opened with root privileges.

Each entry begins with

```
menuentry
```

and ends with this symbol  `}`

Copy paste the entries you want from `grub.cfg` to `40_custom` . Not Ubuntu's entries. Only the entries from `### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###` and below.

When done, save the `40_custom` document.

Run in terminal

```
sudo chmod 644 /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober
sudo chmod 755 /etc/grub.d/40_custom 
sudo update-grub
```

Above commands will remove the execute permissions from 30_os-prober (that scans for other Operating Systems and add the entries) and will give execute permissions to your custom script (40_custom). Last command will update grub with the new values.

Check the new values with

```
cat /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

**Above method is a bit tricky and dangerous**. You should edit the files **very carefully** because you may wind up with a corrupted grub menu or no menu at all. 
If that's the case, you have to use [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair#A2nd_option_:_install_Boot-Repair_in_Ubuntu) from a Live media to restore grub.

More grub tips and tricks can be found in [Ubuntu Wiki/Grub2](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2#Configuring_GRUB_2), for custom menus look [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/CustomMenus).

Good Luck

Comment: Thanks. The manual way is the way I prefer. grub-customizer only gave me remove options, and not hide options. Can I just hash out the entries I don't want to see?

Comment: No you cannot just hash out the entries because at next grub update the file /boot/grub/grub.cfg will be overwritten. You must create your own 40_custom entries. Also the grub-customizer offers you the hide option. The delete is not actual a delete. You can restore the "deleted" entries if you want.